# Parse string array using snakeYaml

Tags: java, arrays, string, snakeyaml

I have a yaml file in this way

```
A: ["aa","bb","cc"]
```

I wonder is there any YAML library can parse this string array rather than using string library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `snakeyaml` like this:

define library in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Mapper class:

```
public class YamlEntity {
    private Map<String, List<String>> value;

    public Map<String, List<String>> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Map<String, List<String>> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "YamlEntity [value=" + value + "]";
    }

 }
```

yaml file like `example.yaml`

```
value: [aa, bb, cc]
```

and your method:

```
public static void readYaml() {
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    InputStream is = App.class.getResourceAsStream("example.yaml");

    Map<String, List<YamlEntity>> ye = yaml.load(is);
    System.out.println(ye.get("value"));
}
```

result is: `[aa, bb, cc]`